# Reingold-Tilford Algorithm with two sides

Tags: java, graph

I need to implement a Reingold-Tilford tree algorithm that distibutes nodes to both sides (left and right) of the root node. i.e. Every second node goes to left. Think of a mindmap.

I tried to modify one implementation (in the Prefuse Java library), but was unable to decipher the code to make the needed changes..

Here's the algorithm in question:

http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/
https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/blob/master/src/prefuse/action/layout/graph/NodeLinkTreeLayout.java

I'm having very hard time finding any resources about this kind of modified algorithm from anywhere. Has anyone here implemented such a thing?